# how to use the es6 "let" keyword properly in a forloop

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, let

Maybe I'm just not understanding the es6 'let' keyword.

### **Question:**

Wy would `iterate(10)` only iterate 4 times? Why is the final output 15?

```
function iterate(count){
  for(let i = 0; i < count; i++){
    i += i
    console.log('inside', i);
  }
  console.log('outside', i);
}
iterate(10);
//0
//inside 2
//inside 6
//inside 14
//outside 15
```

How should I go about using `let` in a `for` loop? When should I think to use `let`.

Comment: How are you using ES6? This might be just a bug of your transpiler. Especially that i does have a value outside of the loop body (instead of throwing an exception) does make this look bogus.

Answer (score 3):

> why would iterate(10) only iterate 4 times?

Because you increment `i` by itself, basically multiply by two in each iteration:

```
i += i
```

It has nothing to do with `let`. The same result would be with `var`.

> why final output be 15?

That should actually throw a Reference error because `i` is not available outside of the loop.

Comment: It has something to do with `let` - because with `let`, this actually should not happen and only modify the local block-scoped variable.

Comment: @Bergi No, `let` 'ed variable is still modifiable within `for` block, just as well as if `var` was used. The only difference is with `let` `console.log('outside', i);` would through Reference error because `i` is not available outside.

Comment: Oops, I stand corrected, it does only iterate four times. [The scope semantics are just weird however](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-forbodyevaluation). The initialisation and each body evaluation do get own scopes with separate bindings for the variable (so if you modify it later, e.g. through closure, they do not interfere as they would with  `var`), but the values of the lexically-scoped variables do get passed into the next iteration explicitly.